# How to print all nodes of a tree?

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

So, I will not provide a code for my problem as I am more interested in theoretical solution.

I have a binary tree and want to print all the ID-s of all the nodes in such an order that nodes on the same height are printed together: first a node on height 0 is printed, than 2 nodes on heigth 1 are printed, than 4 nodes on height 2 are printed and so on. Fathers and Sons of my tree are connected via pointers, nodes on the same height are not connected. Not all Fathers have 2 Sons (some might only have 1 Son).

Theoretically, what are some ways I could print this tree? Is it via recursion?

Comment: This question is far too broad for this site, and cannot be answered in a couple of short paragraphs.  Especially when you need to take into account differing numbers of children and potentially very wide trees.

Comment: I can be done in several ways, each one with pros and cons, I would suggest to complement the question with some more valuable details of your current structure and what you would like to consider to achieve the result.

Comment: Have you tried applying the **BFS** traversal algorithm ?

- It uses a queue data structure.
- It will traverse the tree level-wise. 

I would suggest you to do a bit of research before asking questions on public forums.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is probably breadth first search. An easy way to implement this is by creating a global queue, and adding nodes to it to search as you go through the tree. Provided it's a finite tree, you'll be done once you've searched all the nodes in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do level order traversal. Your problem is exactly [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/level-order-tree-traversal).